# Django auth.group custom permission

Tags: python, django, authentication

im creating a custom group with some permissions like this

// create new group

```
new_group, created = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='AdminGroup')
ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
```

//  Add permission to new group

```
p3 = Permission.objects.create(
    codename='DELETE', name='can_Delete', content_type=ct)
new_group.permissions.add(p3)
```

now i want to check if user has this permission like this

```
user_right = request.user.has_perm('can_Delete')
print(user_right)
```

this print returns me false. how ??

and of course, i added this group to the user like this

```
g = Group.objects.get(name='AdminGroup')
request.user.groups.add(g)
```

and another thing, 
I've checked this in admin panel group is assigned with permission successfully

can someone explain to me
 how this is false ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add User table (Which is the class in our models.py or directly auth_user table) before the access permission. And make sure that you have added authentication backend in setting.py in case of you have used auth_user table.

`user_right = request.user.has_perm('User.can_Delete')`

Let me know it is working or not.

Comment: Try with request.user.has_perm('App_name.can_Delete')

Comment: i've added this 'AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )'

Comment: if I print the permissions than it works fine and prints all given permissions.

Comment: i think the problem is with has_perm is there any other way to do the same?

Comment: have you used allauth?